# How to use polynomial or conformal transformation

Tags: transformation, conformal-geometry

In my research, I came to a transformation problem. The simple version is an initial circle (or sphere) region is advected by some deformational flow. After some time the circle will be deformed into other shapes.

At the beginning, I used linear transformation (rotation, shearing, translating), but I found this is not enough when the flow is extremely deformative. The circle is stretched into long ellipse due the linear nature of the transformation, which should already be bent.

So I decide to try high-order polynomial transformation as shown in the figure. I am not very familiar with polynomial transformation, could it solve this problem? In addition, I also need an inverse transformation, but the high-order polynomial will add some difficulties.

Any input is appreciated!

[image]

**Update:**

I decided to use conformal transformation which should be easier to solve, especially when inverse the transformation, as suggested by @Shuchang. The new diagram is shown as:

[image]

If we know the coordinates of the control points and the rotation matrixes on them, how to define the transformation function $f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{y}(\mathbf{x})$?

Comment: There are many nonlinear transformation to make a deformation and polynomial transformation, in my opinion, may not be a good choice. Could you specify what's the intention behind this?

Comment: @Shuchang I am developing a Lagrangian numerical transport scheme, which uses many particles to discretise the continuous tracer. In deformative flow, the shape that the particle presents will be changed. This shape is used when interpolating the tracer mass carried by particles onto other spots (like a mesh).

Comment: I'm not sure but suggest conformal transformation. Essential you are aligning two curves.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use polynomial transformations? If not, you could represent the initial shape using spline curves and transform it be moving the parameters or control points. -- Second thought: You would gain some flexibility at moderate degrees by considering rational functions instead of polynomials.

Comment: @LutzL I used to represent the shape by polygon, but it was a nightmare when the flow is extremely deformative. I would like to use transformation because it provide a convenient way to calculate the transformed coordinate.

Comment: @Shuchang Thanks for reminding me conformal transformation (the Jacobian matrix is a scalar times a rotation matrix). I think I can put some small probes associated with the particle which are used to sense the vorticity of the flow (rotation). The divergence is represented by the location of the probes themselves.

Comment: @Shuchang Do you have any references about the conformal transformation function where the rotation matrix is given on a few points. Thank you!